# What should the browserslistrc of my Vue webapp look like to support a very old version of Safari?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I have an old iPad gen 1 running iOS 5 that I want to get my Vue webapp (created with Vue CLI) working on. Therefore I decided to update my `browserslistrc` to the following to support the old version Safari browser:

```
> 1%
last 2 versions
not dead
ios_saf 5.1
ios_saf 5.0
safari 5.1
safari 5.0
```

My `npm build` command is the following: `vue-cli-service-build --modern`

Now when I run `npm run build` and deploy the code to my server, the webapp is not displayed, when I visit the server on my iPad (safari). The webapp is visible on modern browsers though.

I have also tried `last 20 versions` in my `browserslistrc`, which even included versions before safari 5.0 (when running `npx browserslist`). Unfortunately, the webapp still did not work on my iPad.

Am I missing something? I have followed https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html, but I could not get the webapp to work on my iPad.

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "sass": "^1.27.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-device-detector": "^1.1.6",
    "vue-material": "^1.0.0-beta-15",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

My `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```